# No network interfaces detected when installing Ubuntu Server on Mac Mini

Tags: system-installation, broadcom, mac, mac-mini, nic

I have a new Mac Mini (MacMini6,1 late 2012) that I would like to install Ubuntu Server 13.04 (`ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64+mac.iso`) on. But it seems like Ubuntu Server isn't able to detect my network interface, because I get the message:

> No network interfaces detected

How can I fix this issue? Is there any module or driver that I can add for this?

---

I have now tried to install Ubuntu Server with the `build-essentials` package and downloaded source to the tg3-driver as suggested in the answers. But when compiling (with the `make` command) I get errors:

```
...
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/jonas/tg3-3.129d/tg3.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jonas/tg3-3.129d] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic`
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you may find this other question useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/288454/ubuntu-13-04-on-mac-mini-6-2-ethernet-port-broadcom-netxtreme-bcm57766-not-detec

Comment: Does lspci show the card? Do you get link light? lspci should give you a clue on what type of card it is. You may need the restricted drivers for that card or the broadcom packages if you're doing minimal-cd.

Comment: @universalhacker: the wired nic has id `[14e4:1686]` BCM57766 and the wireless nic has id `[14e4:4331]` BCM4331, from `lspci`.

Comment: For these error that you got see this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561261/cc1-warnings-being-treated-as-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Go into bios; check to see if Virtualization (VT-d) is enabled.
Try again.
If that doesnt work...

Get driver here: http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtreme_desktop.php
Copy to USB disk and configure.

Comment: see my update, my compilation fails

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my Mac Mini, and been having all sorts of problems, one of which is Network.  So here is what I did.

I updated the [firmware](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1616)

Then I installed Ubuntu without network, and when the installation was done, I downloaded and installed the [driver](http://www.broadcom.com/support/license.php?file=570x/linux-3.129d.zip), and it all worked OK.

Now, my Mini is a G4 mini, and of course with different hardware.  **The links included are for your machine**, but do **make sure of the firmware before you update it**.  I don't know that this will work for you, but it did for me.  You can try and see if it'll work for you.

To compile the driver:

Inside the tg3-3.129d.tar.gz file, there's a readme.txt that has the instructions.  Make and all that you need to install are inside the tg3-3.129d.tar.gz file.

Here what I did.  I made sure that I disconnected LAN.  I copied the file to my Downloads folder, right clicked on the file, and clicked on extract here.  The I went to the extracted folder, from terminal, and typed:

```
make
```

That compiled the driver for my Kernel.  Inside the file one of the steps says to do `cd src`, I didn't do that, just typed `make` at the prompt, and that did it.

Comment: I have to compile the driver, how do I get `make` and such tools without Internet connectivity?

Comment: See the added info in my answer.  That the way I did it, and it works OK :)

Comment: I my extracted `tg3-3.129d/` folder I only have C source files and a Makefile, but not any `Make` binaries.

Comment: see my update, my compilation fails

Comment: Did the .deb file work?

Comment: The dev-file was for build tools? I did a new installation and installed the `build essentials` package instead, but now the driver compilation fails

Comment: No the file I include in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwytyn7zr91xzdp/tg3_3.129d-1_amd64.deb), the conversion from rpm to deb.  Did you try that?